# Nested if statement not firing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am posting data to my db, however, before I do I have set in my php to echo out any issues. When the 'data != 'signup success' it should run the if within it, this does not work. Any ideas ?

PHP:

```
if($u == ""){
    echo "Please create a username";
    exit();
}
```

Js:

```
var submitBtn = $('#signUpBtn');

    submitBtn.on('click', function() {

        var fn = $('#fname'),
            ln = $('#lname'),
            u = $('#uname'),
            e = $('#email'),
            p = $('#pword1'),
            p2 = $('#pword2'),
            fnVal = fn.val(),
            lnVal = ln.val(),
            uVal = u.val(),
            eVal = e.val(),
            pVal = p.val(),
            p2Val = p2.val();

        $.post('phpsrc/parsers/signUp.php', 
            {fn: fnVal, ln: lnVal, u: uVal, e: eVal, p: pVal}, 

            function(data) {

                if (data != 'signup success') {
                    if (data === 'Please create a username') {
                        alert('uname');
                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
        );
    });
```

Comment: Try `if (data.trim() === 'Pleas....` and see if you have whitespace issues. As a sidenote, jQuery has a `serialize` method

Comment: LIkely your ajax request is failing: "If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError() method. Alternatively, as of jQuery 1.5, the .error() method of the jqXHR object returned by jQuery.post() is also available for error handling."

Comment: Instead of validating a string directly from the body, I would JSON encode it. It will easily become a mess for you otherwise.

Comment: You should probably put something in that empty else too.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, your method has worked ! However I am definitely going to look into JSON decoding. Any pointers to learning resources ?

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off json encoding the data:

```
if($u == ""){
    $data = array("response" => "Please create a username");
    exit(json_encode($data));
}
```

Allowing you to check the response in your ajax request like this:

```
function(data) {

    if (data.response !== 'signup success') {
        if (data.response == 'Please create a username') {
            alert('uname');
        }
    } else {
        alert('something');
    }
}
```

Comment: While I agree 100%, there's as much chance the OP isn't getting a http 2xx response. You might want to expand your example to include jQuery error handling

Comment: Touche @Basic , I didn't think of that avenue. Will append shortly :)

Comment: I implemented your example, however it still doesn't give me the "alert('uname');".